# ValueError: malformed node or string

Tags: python

I am not sure why I cannot use `np.matrix` or a `matrix` like the following:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix('3 -5; 2 7')
print(A)
B = np.matrix('13; 81')
print(B)
A_det = np.linalg.det(A)
print(A_det)
X_m = np.matrix(A)
X_m[:, 0] = B
print(X_m)
Y_m = np.matrix(A)
Y_m[:, 1] = B
print(Y_m)
x = np.linalg.det(X_m) / A_det
y = np.linalg.det(Y_m) / A_det

print(x)
print(y)
X = np.matrix('x; y')
O = A @ X - B 
print(O)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 19
     17 print(x)
     18 print(y)
---> 19 X = np.matrix('x; y')
     20 O = A @ X - B 
     21 print(O)

ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x2dc0210>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [`np.matrix`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html):

> If data is a string, it is interpreted as a matrix with commas or
> spaces separating columns, and semicolons separating rows.

This means the data passed in the string, must be literals (`1`, or `1.5`) not variables (or names).

Use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead:

```
X = np.matrix(f'{x}; {y}')
```

The error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x2dc0210>
```

you are getting is because numpy is using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to create the matrix (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b0b7a066c393a1d7cc69e9a6db7c7c7a3602b293/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L27)).

Answer (score -1):

The variables x and y haven't been initialized yet. Try below code instead

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('3 -5; 2 7')
print(A)
B = np.matrix('13; 81')
print(B)
A_det = np.linalg.det(A)
print(A_det)
X_m = np.matrix(A)
X_m[:, 0] = B
print(X_m)
Y_m = np.matrix(A)
Y_m[:, 1] = B
print(Y_m)
x = np.linalg.det(X_m) / A_det
y = np.linalg.det(Y_m) / A_det

print(x)
print(y)
X = np.matrix([[x], [y]])
O = A @ X - B 
print(O)
```